How to place at least one of the two idential apples and one orange, each on a black square, with two black squares on a 3x3 grid
This is an interview question that I am preparing for and would appreciate your thoughts on my approach: How many ways to place at least one of the two identical apples and an orange - each on a black square - on a 3x3 grid with two black squares. Assume you can place only one fruit on each square.
Here is my approach:

count the number of ways to place at least one apple and an orange on two (black) squares: there are two possibilities (Orange,Apple) and (Apple,Orange).
count the number of ways to arrange two black squares on a 3x3 grid: $\binom{9}{2}=36$
multiply (1) and (2): $2\times 36=72$

Is this a sound approach? Thank you for your help.

It seems that the word "at least" is misleading.

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but don't forget that the other apple has 7 places it can be placed too.

Thanks, that's a great point. So it should be $72\times 7=504$.

Could apple-apple on the black squares not also be possible?

The question is poorly phrased and "at least" is misleading as pointed out by another comment, in my opinion. The question is somewhat clear about stating that an orange should be on one of the two black squares.
